# Print all combinations of a 3D vector

Tags: c++, vector, combinations

Suppose I have a `vector<vector<vector<int> > > result`.

The only size I know before hand is the inner and outer vector, which are of size `k`.

if I print `result` I get this (for `k = 3`):

```
i = 0

0 1 2
3 4 5

i = 1

6 7 8
9 10 11
12 13 14

i = 2

15 16 17
18 19 20
```

What I need to do is to print every combinations of `k` rows from each of vector of vectors of `i`'s. In other words, what I need is the following output:

```
0 1 2
6 7 8
15 16 17

0 1 2
6 7 8
18 19 20

0 1 2
9 10 11
15 16 17

...

3 4 5
12 13 14
18 19 20
```

Hope I was clear about the desired output. I have tried a thousand of different loops, trying to save in another `vector<vector<int> >` but no success so far. I really am lost and any help would be greatly appreaciated.

The code to generate the above output is here:

(I'm sorry, I know it is an ugly code but it was the closest I could get to demonstrate my problem in a MCVE code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<vector<vector<int> > > result;
    int k = 3;
    vector<vector<int> > randomVectors;
    //I'll create seven random vectors
    //In my original problem, I don't have this number beforehand
    int number = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        vector<int> temp;
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++){
            temp.push_back(number);
            number++;
        }
        randomVectors.push_back(temp);
    }
    //Vector of vector to assign to "result"
    vector<vector<int> > randomVectors_0;
    randomVectors_0.push_back(randomVectors[0]);
    randomVectors_0.push_back(randomVectors[1]);
    vector<vector<int> > randomVectors_1;
    randomVectors_1.push_back(randomVectors[2]);
    randomVectors_1.push_back(randomVectors[3]);
    randomVectors_1.push_back(randomVectors[4]);
    vector<vector<int> > randomVectors_2;
    randomVectors_2.push_back(randomVectors[5]);
    randomVectors_2.push_back(randomVectors[6]);

    result.push_back(randomVectors_0);
    result.push_back(randomVectors_1);
    result.push_back(randomVectors_2);

    cout << "Printing the 3D vector" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        cout << "i = " << i << endl << endl;
        for(int j = 0; j < result[i].size(); j++){
            for(int m = 0; m < k; m++){
                cout << result[i][j][m] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler version: gcc (tdm-1) 4.7.1

Comment: i suggest you to fill the array with elements `100*i + 10*j + k`, then you can simply read off what loop you need from the expected output

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion @user463035818. Can you explain  a little more?

Comment: the thing is that i dont understand your expected output, it only makes sense when you know how the elements are stored in the vectors, eg at what index is the element with value `19`? If you use the values I proposed then the element with value `123` is `result[1][2][3]`. Now if you write down the expected output with those values you can directly read of what loops you need

Comment: ...or make it `result[1][2][3] = 234` (you cant have `0` as leading digit...)

Comment: @user463035818 The numbers I used are random. In my original problem they can be any positive integer value. My desired output is: get the first line of `i = 0`, then first line of `i = 1` then first line of `i = 2`. At this point I formed one `k x k` matrix. After this I want to make a different matrix. I'm sorry I'm not being very clear

Comment: then dont use random numbers. Almost nothing is as bad for debugging as random numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a `rows_to_print` vector that starts with all 0's. Then once a loop, it'll increment the last value by 1. If that value is greater than the size of the last vector, then reset it to 0 and increment the next value up the list, etc... you're done looping when every value in `rows_to_print` is greater than the size of each of the vectors:

```
void print_rows(std::vector<size_t> rows, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> v) {
    for(size_t x = 0; x < v.size(); x++) {
        for(size_t y = 0; y < v.at(x).at(rows.at(x)).size(); y++) {
            std::cout << v.at(x).at(rows.at(x)).at(y) << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

bool increment_rows(std::vector<size_t> &rows, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> v) {
    if(!rows.size()) return false; //empty rows, BAD
    rows.at(rows.size() - 1)++;
    for(int x = rows.size() - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        if(rows.at(x) >= v.at(x).size()) {
            if(x <= 0) { return false; } //first row is done, then we're done!
            rows.at(x-1)++; //increment previous row and set us back to 0 (overflow)
            rows.at(x) %= v.at(x).size();
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main() {
    ...

    std::vector<size_t> rows_to_print(k, 0);
    print_rows(rows_to_print, result);
    while(increment_rows(rows_to_print, result)) {
        print_rows(rows_to_print, result);
    }
}
```

See it in action here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/0b6TWR)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears your code is in an infinite loop while printing `0 1 2` , `6 7 8`, `15 16 17`

Comment: @ihavenoidea I forgot a reference! See my latest edit. You can also see it working with the link I just provided.

Comment: This is most likely my fault so I deeply apologize. You got the idea of problem, however in your solution, for example the print `0 1 2`, `9 10 11`, `12 13 14` is not a valid one because both vectors `9 10 11` and `12 13 14` are in the same `i`.

Comment: @ihavenoidea Are you talking about output when you run the program on your end? Or the ideone link? If the latter, I'm using a different set of a vectors than you. I printed out the values of the vectors on top of the ideone output. If the former, I'm going to need to see your code and full output...

Comment: Oh I didn't see that you changed the way of the result vector. I'll check it and will come back to you

Comment: @ihavenoidea it was easier for me to generate it in one line if I made all of the second vectors the same size, so I didn't go to the trouble of matching yours :p

Comment: @ihavenoidea happy to help :)

Comment: Hey @scohe001 , any idea of the time complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: @ihavenoidea let's define your matrix as `K x Ji x K` (where `Ji`is the size of each i'th second vector). Then we'll need to print `J1 * J2 * J3 * ... * Jn` groups where each group has `K` rows with `K` columns, or `K*K` items. If we call the largest `Ji`, `J` then worst case (where all `Ji`'s are the max) we'll have `K*K*J` items to print. So you could say this has a complexity of `O(K*K*J)` if you're measuring items printed. The same would be true of the printing complexity of any algorithm since you want the same output. Does that answer your question?